# Specific key in Python 3.5.0 running on Windows 8.0

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.5.0  in windows 8.1 and I am trying to make a program that guesses your animal and I don't know how to tell the computer to record specific keys to ask the next question let's say I want to press the Y key for yes and the program says error because it does not know the Y key and what to do with it.

## This program guesses your animal

```
print('Hello, do you want to play a game')
print('Great lets play a guessing game')
print('Think of an animal and I will ask you different questions and I will try to guess your animal')
print('Question #1 Can your animal fly Press Y for yes and N for no')
input(N):
    print('You picked no')
```

[The error is "invalid Syntax This a screenshot of my problem .jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIT08.jpg)

Comment: Without the code we can't be that much helpful. Please edit your question with your code.

Comment: I will do that thank you do not leave me, please

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `input()` function in a wrong way.

Looking at the python [`input([prompt])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function doc:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

Said so and looking at what you wan to achieve, you can:

1. write directly the question inside the `print()` function
2. assign the value read from the input function to a variable
3. test the variable to see if the user choose N or Y

This is how your code should be in order to achieve what you are looking for:

```
print('Hello, do you want to play a game')
print('Great lets play a guessing game')
print('Think of an animal and I will ask you different questions and I will try to guess your animal')
fly = input('Question #1 Can your animal fly? (Press Y for yes and N for no)')
if fly == 'N':
    print('You picked no')
elif fly == 'Y':
    print('You picked yes')
```